# How would you write/pronounce the Japanese version of the following Chinese name?

Tags: kanji, names, chinese

This is the name: 陳威穎 (Chen Wei-Ying).

I've always been curious about this topic because Japanese names are written in Kanji. However, they usually have 4 characters.

So I wonder how would that Chinese name above be transformed into Japanese?

I consulted [Jisho](https://jisho.org/). And I'm pretty sure 陳 would become Chin.

As for 威穎, I get something not very Japanese sounding on Google Translate: Gi Ei (at least, when referring to Japanese names).

However on Jisho I get:

> たけし 【威】 Given name, gender not specified
>   1. Takeshi​
>
> さとし 【穎】 Male given name
>   1. Satoshi​

So I'm very confused. What the Japanese version of the name is supposed to be? At least, the Japanese-sounding version?

(I'm a bit new to this site so I'm not sure if this question is off-topic. If it is, Sumimasen.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could transcribe it using the *on'yomi* reading of the kanji characters:

> 陳威穎 => ちん・い・えい (chin i ei)

Examples for each character: [**陳**舜臣](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E9%99%B3%E8%88%9C%E8%87%A3), and [**威**海市](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%A8%81%E6%B5%B7%E5%B8%82), and [張**穎**](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%BC%B5%E7%A9%8E)

Since *on'yomi* is an approximation of the original Chinese pronunciation, this is what's usually done for translating names.

If you want to create a "Japanese sounding" name, you could adapt the given name as:

> 威穎 => たけひで (takehide)

Like the pronunciation in [林**威**宏](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E6%9E%97%E5%A8%81%E5%AE%8F) or [山崎一**穎**](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%B1%B1%E5%B4%8E%E4%B8%80%E7%A9%8E).

Comment: Thanks for answering! So the two-letter name will be "Chin Iei"? That looks a bit strange to me. Takehide sounds good.

Comment: @alex Well, yes, at that point you're transcribing from Chinese into Japanese into English, so it's bound to feel weird. In Japanese you can just write out the kanji characters.